# $R^2$ that takes the number of covariates into account

Tags: r-squared, predictor

How do I report the $R^2$ that takes the number of covariates in the model into account?

Comment: it's called adjusted $R^2$. it's calculation for the case of $p$ covariates + an intercept is $R_{adj}^2= R^2-(1-R^2)\frac{p}{n-p-1}$.

Comment: Search this site for "adjusted R-squared", might be a duplicate.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52517/why-is-adjusted-r-squared-less-than-r-squared-if-adjusted-r-squared-predicts-the   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92081/what-happens-to-adjusted-r-squared-as-sample-size-increases    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative

Comment: It doesn't look like a duplicate to me, but I'm not sure it's a good question.

Comment: When you say "how do you report" can you clarify exactly what you mean?