# Is it "cheating" to augment data by adding noise to the label?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, modeling, data-augmentation

I have a data set that I'd like to augment by adding noise to the label. I've seen people on Kaggle duplicate each row twice and add 1 and subtract 1 to the label

Whenever I do this and then do a train-test split, the performance of my model jumps from approximately 0.7 $R^2$ to over 0.95 $R^2$, making me wonder if it's invalid for me to do this. If the model is being trained on a row and then tested on a slightly altered but essentially the same row, that probably makes the validation performance invalid, right? If so, how could I do the augmentation properly? Should I do the train-test split and *then* augment?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that the test set contains some of the synthetic points?

Comment: Yes, I did the train/test split after augmenting. So I had an initial dataset of ~3500 samples, augmented to ~10500, and then split into train/test. I assume that's invalid but not 100% sure what a proper process would look like

Comment: I'm testing and if I do the train/test split on the initial ~3500 samples and *then* do the data augmentation on both the train and test set, the performance improves. It also improves if I only do so on the train set. Not sure which, if any, of these options are 'valid'

Comment: See the effects of sample size on $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92081/what-happens-to-adjusted-r-squared-as-sample-size-increases#:~:text=Increasing%20Sample.Size%20makes%20adjusted%20R%202%20approach%20R,work%20with%20manually%20entered%20data%20or%20multiple%20predictors.)